# Can Raspbery Pi 4 hardware decode 4k@60hz H.265 10bit video?

Tags: gpu, pi-4

I have seen it has H.265 support, but not specifically for 10 bit. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: i've just checked it out, 3840 x 2160 60 fps 10 bit is running like potatoe (raspberry pi 4b 4gb ram)

Comment: Just to be sure, does that mean the playback is "potato quality", i.e. quite bad?

Comment: It is either at 60 FPS or it isn't, it won't decode a "wrong" video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this document](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1560/1473/files/Inside_Raspberry_Pi_4.pdf?2142), it actually supports "HEVCv2 Main 4:4:4 10", where the 10 at the end means that it actually supports 10 bit decoding, which also hints it might support HDR.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with an official documentation which states that 10 bit 4K HEVC decoding is supported. But from my experience, it works.

I have just tried to play a 10 bit HDR (BT.2020) HEVC (H.265) video which has a resolution of 3840x2160 at 23.976 fps and is encoded with profile@tier Main 10@L5@High and bitrate of about 15 Mb/s. The device that I have tried to play it on is a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with Kodi 19.1.

The playback was smooth. I have used a 4K TV via HDMI 2.0 as the display with the resolution set to 3840x2160 at 60 fps and with the "HDR mode" (which, I assume, means that input in HDR colorspaces and larger bit depths is supported) enabled on the TV.